# What's the difference between document.getElementById("test").value and document.getElementById("test").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

```
document.getElementById("test").value

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
```

Does the first mean the address and the second mean the value stored at the address?  Also, where can I find documentation on the `value` property?

Comment: The [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/) has a good [reference on the HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) .

Comment: @BrianRogers - Please do not recommend w3schools. See http://w3fools.com for why.

Comment: @Oded - I have found their HTML DOM reference to be quite useful.  If you feel so strongly about the site, it would be more constructive for you to recommend an alternative reference for the HTML DOM.

Comment: @BrianRogers - Certainly. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) is great. Factual and correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.value` gives you the currently-set value of a form element (`input`, `select`, `textarea`), whereas `.innerHTML` builds an HTML string based on the DOM nodes the element contains.

For a simple example, go to the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sSSsU/), and enter a new value into the `input` and then move out of the input.

The test uses the following JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('input').onchange = function(){
    alert('innerHTML: ' + document.getElementById('input').innerHTML + '; whereas value: ' + document.getElementById('input').value);
};
```

(The above text updated, following a comment left by [am not i am](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/am-not-i-am), in comments below.)

Comment: I would love it if you would instead say *"`.innerHTML` builds an HTML string based on the DOM nodes the element contains"* (or something similar) since a DOM node doesn't strictly have any "HTML" content.

Comment: @amnotiam, agreed. My text updated, and thank you for the clarification. =)

Answer (score 3):

some `HTML` elements have an attribute `"value"`, such as `<input/>`some others don't have it.

if you want to modify them, you may use the DOM attribute (used with `Javascript`) `innerHTML` (if they have any). this attribute represents the content of an element, so it may be used for elements accepting to nest other element such as `<div/>`,

Answer (score 3):

Many elements in HTML can have an ID, so the definition of `value` will change for each.

`value` will be essentially what that element understands as a value. For example, an `<input type=text>` would give you the text inside.

`innerHTML` will be what HTML code is inside. For example, a `<TR>` would have its child `TD`'s, plus whatever else is in there.

`value` and `innerHTML` can (usually) be written to, as well as read.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with how some tags work based on their attributes where others work on the text between the opening and closing tags.

`.value` retrieves whatever value is set for the `value` attribute of the tag. `.innerHTML` retrieves whatever is in between the opening and closing tag.

For example if the HTML tag was
`<input type="text" value="Enter name here" id="user_name" />`
and you used the JavaScript
`var name = document.getElementById('user_name').value`
would declare a variable `name` and give it the value "Enter name here" (assuming the user didn't change it). On the other hand if you have HTML like
`<div id="abc">blah blah</div>`
then you would use
`var text = document.getElementById('abc')`
and that would set the variable `text` to "blah blah".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByid('test').value
```

is use to give value in a text field. Like

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
```

Now it put value in this text feild.

While `document.getElementByid('test').innerHTML`
is use to to give value in a specified area. Like

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Now it print the value within the div area.