# Salary calculator in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function calculate(){   
     var a = parseFloat(frmMain.name.value);
     var b = parseFloat(frmMain.Salary.value);
     var c = parseFloat(frmMain.taxrate.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmMain">
       Name <input type ="text" id="name" /><br />
       Salary <input type ="text" id="Salary" /><br />
       tax rate <input type ="text" id="taxrate" /><br />
       <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
       <input type="reset" value="Clear" /><br />
       Sammary<textarea cols="20" rows="5" ></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i try to make it like this but i dont know how to get the salary and the name and taxrate put it in the comment or notes place may any body help ?
the program should get the name  and taxrate and salary and print it inside the textarea using javascript when i click on calculate ? i dont have an idea how to do this

Comment: Have you searched the internet? Have you followed a free basic javascript tutorial? Why are you treating a `name` as a float? Have you looked into using a javascript library like jQuery--I highly recommend that.

Comment: Brought to you by Carls Jr.

Comment: @ErikE: the OP is obviously missing some basic js knowledge, suggesting jQuery at this point seems overkill.

Comment: user, all you would need is getElementById and InnerHTML

Comment: @Seki I think you are off base. jQuery is *easier* than plain vanilla js programming. Finding information how to accomplish basic tasks in jQuery is probably easier and imho a better learning curve. Triple ko is more fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhfRA/)**

```
function calculate(){   
     var a = frmMain.name.value;
     var b = parseFloat(frmMain.Salary.value);
     var c = parseFloat(frmMain.taxrate.value);

    frmMain.summary.value = "Name     :"+a+"\nSalary   :"+b+"\nTax Rate :"+c;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to add an id to the textarea, maybe `id="texty"` after that you can get that elemnt with javascript, like this, `var area = document.getElementById('texty');` and from there you use the `.innerHTML` attribute to set its value.

`area.innerHTML = b*c;` <- this math isn't what you're after but I used a simple case to show you how its done! :)

If you're more keen on using `value` then read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057242/whats-the-difference-between-document-getelementbyidtest-value-and-document) to understand the diffrences between `.innerHTML` and `.value`

Also reading the JS docs on MDN is very good reference, I'll put a link in the bottom!

Check out the tinker below!

[Tinker.io here](https://tinker.io/279f3)

[MDN JS Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function calculate(){   
     var a = frmMain.name.value;
     var b = parseFloat(frmMain.Salary.value);
     var c = parseFloat(frmMain.taxrate.value);
var area = document.getElementById("text");
area.innerHTML='Name : '+a+'\nSalary : '+b+'\nTax Rate : '+c;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmMain">
       Name <input type ="text" id="name" /><br />
       Salary <input type ="text" id="Salary" /><br />
       tax rate <input type ="text" id="taxrate" /><br />
       <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
       <input type="reset" value="Clear" /><br />
       Sammary<textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="text"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```