# How to correctly use innerHTML to change text in text field

Tags: javascript, dom

There are 3 text fields in my programm. First two im using to write some words in there, then after pressing button the longest word should appear in third text field, but nothing happens.

I was trying to use innerHTML but guess im using it incorrectly.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick= function(){
                var a = document.getElementById("one")
                var b = document.getElementById("two")
                var c = document.getElementById("three")               
                if(a.value.length>b.value.length){
                    c.innerHTML = a.value 
                } else{
                    c.innerHTML = b.value 
                }
            }
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="one"/>
        <input type="text" id="two"/>
        <input type="text" id="three"/>
        <button id="button">Button</button>
```

So nothing happens with third text field when im pressing button there is no longest word. All code working correctly, only problem with innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` if you want to set values in `input` not `innerHTML`

```js
      document.getElementById("button").onclick= function(){
            var a = document.getElementById("one")
            var b = document.getElementById("two")
            var c = document.getElementById("three")               
            if(a.value.length>b.value.length){
                c.value = a.value 
            } else{
                c.value = b.value 
            }
        }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="one"/>
    <input type="text" id="two"/>
    <input type="text" id="three"/>
    <button id="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`innerHTML` ** : It refers to html content inside an element. This is used to get or set the html content. Generally used for div, span and p.

**`value`** : It refers to actual value of an element. Generally used for input elements.

*Refer* : [Diff between value & innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057242/whats-the-difference-between-document-getelementbyidtest-value-and-document)

**Hence in your case, you should use c.value instead of c.innerHTML.**